# for loops in Python - how to modify i inside the loop

Tags: python, for-loop

This code was written in Python 3.6 in Jupyter Notebooks.  In other languages, I am pretty sure I built loops that looked like this:

```
endRw=5
lenDF=100   # 1160

for i in range(0, lenDF):
    print("i: ", i)
    endIndx = i + endRw
    if endIndx > lenDF:
                endIndx = lenDF

    print("Range to use: ", i, ":", endIndx)
    # this line is a mockup for an index that is built and used
    # in the real code to do something to a pandas DF

    i = endIndx
    print("i at end of loop", i)
```

In testing though, `i` does not get reset to `endIndx` and so the loop does not build the intended index values.

I was able to solve this problem and get what I was looking for by building a while loop like this:

```
endRw=5
lenDF=97   # 1160
i = 0
while i < lenDF:
    print("i: ", i)
    endIndx = i + endRw
    if endIndx > lenDF:
                endIndx = lenDF

    print("Range to use: ", i, ":", endIndx)
    # this line is a mockup for an index that is built and used
    # in the real code to do something to a pandas DF

    i = endIndx
    print("i at end of loop: ", i)
```

Question:  is there a way to modify the `i` from inside the `for` loop in python?  Is there a way to do what I did with the `while` loop using a `for` loop in Python?

Solved the problem with `while` but just curious about this.

Comment: You did not clarify what your goal actully is. If you just want to end the whole loop, use `break`.

Comment: @KlausD. - the output of my test loop is a bit long, but if you run the while loop in Python, the goal is to get identical output to what the while loop generates but do it with a for loop.  More specifically, I originally got into trouble because I have modified the i-variable in for loops in other languages the way I attempted to in the for loop shown, but it did not work in Python,  I see some great answers on here as to why so I will have to run some tests to figure out which one comes closest to this goal I think.

Comment: @TMWP Just saw your edit to my answer being rejected. Why don't you make it a separate answer; I think it would be worthwhile.

Comment: @PaulPanzer It takes the concepts you showed me and integrates them into the original code so they work.  In this respect, it does not feel like a new answer to me, it feels like a more complete one.  Further, an answer that borrows your concepts in my humble opinion should not compete with yours.  If you can't uncancel or accept my last edit now that is rejected, but like this idea, let me know and I will edit it again so you can accept it.

Comment: @PaulPanzer if after reading my earlier comment, you still think it needs to be posted as a new answer, let me know and I may yet do it.  I just liked the idea of adding to your for completeness instead.

Comment: Yes, I think you should post it --- though I have no strong views on this: certainly you shouldn't worry about competing with my post. I'm reluctant to reverse the rejection --- if that's possible at all --- since I don't feel like stepping on anybody's toes right now.

Comment: no problem.  I will draft it later.

Comment: @PaulPanzer you will find the new answer added to this question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for` loops operate on iterables. In `for i in range(0, lenDF)`, `i` is assigned the next value in the range on each round of the loop regardless of how it is used in the loop. The question then, is whether there is a clean way to write an iterable that does what you want. In this case, all you want is to advance by a fixed step and adjust the final step length to account for the end of data.

```
endRw=5
lenDF=97   # 1160

for i in range(0, lenDF, endRw):
    endIndx = min(i+endRw, lenDF)
    print("Range to use: ", i, ":", endIndx)
```

Answer (score 6):

You *can* modify the loop variable in a `for` loop, the problem is that `for` loops in Python are not like "old-style" `for` loops in e.g. Java, but more like "new-style" `for-each` loops.

In Python, `for i in range(0, 10):` does not behave like `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {`, but like `for (int i : new int[] {0, 1, ..., 10}}`.

That is, in each iteration of the loop, the loop head will not modify the loop variable (e.g. increment it), but *assign a new value to it*, i.e. the next value from the given iterable (a `range` in your case). Thus, any modification that you did in the previous iteration are overwritten.

If you want to loop a known number of iterations or for every item in an iterable, use a `for` loop, but if you want to loop until a certain condition (no longer) holds, as in your case, use `while`.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is unlikely to be useful, but since you were just curious:
The closest I think to what you want to do would be using a generator and its `send` method:

```
>>> def jumpable_range(start, stop):
...     i = start
...     while i <= stop:
...         j = yield i
...         i = i + 1 if j is None else j
... 
>>> R = jumpable_range(2, 10)
>>> 
>>> for i in R:
...     if i==5:
...         i = R.send(8)
...     print(i)
... 
2
3
4
8
9
10
>>>
```

Comment: I like this solution. Its a more general way to provide feedback to an iterator. I don't think its needed in the particular case, but is well worth noting. It would be interesting if it returned both i and the end index so that the caller didn't need to make that calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the original question literally:

- @Tobias_k provides [a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671346/7525365) of when to use `while` versus `for` loops, and the use case of this question fits `while` better (at least for Python).  In short: you cannot directly modify the `i` in `for i in` because of how this code works under the covers in Python.  So `while` should be used for a use case where you need to change your counter inside a loop (in Python).
- @tdelaney provides a good answer in terms of refactoring the code using a Python `for` loop given the way Python behaves (the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671440/7525365) to this question).
- @PaulPanzer [provides concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50671414/7525365) that, while over-complicated, are useful to students to explore new concepts; but the answer solves the `for` loop problem by using a `while` loop inside an iterator and calling that into the `for` loop.

Even so, the concepts explored that play to the use of `yield` and iterators are worth exploring.  If we take these concepts and attempt to re-write the original code to exploit them, this is what that code would look like:

```
def jumpable_range(start, stop):
    i = start
    while i <= stop:
        j = yield i
        i = i + 1 if j is None else j

endRw=5
lenDF=97   # 1160

Q = jumpable_range(0,lenDF)
for i in Q:
    print("i: ", i)
    endIndx = i + endRw
    if endIndx > lenDF:
                endIndx = lenDF

    if i == endIndx: break

    print("Range to use: ", i, ":", endIndx)
    # this line is a mockup for an index that is built and used
    # in the real code to do something to a pandas DF

    i = Q.send(endIndx-1)
    print("i at end of loop", i)
```

Comment: Nice summary. One little nitpick: `jumpable_range` is not a function, it is a generator.

Comment: Thanks.  Fixing that now.

Answer (score -1):

You  always can  set  the  value of  `i` in a `for` loop. The problem is  your  setting value statement is  before the  implicit `for`  loop  setting value statement and  covered   by  latter.  You  cannot change  the  rule to make latter  statement  useless. You shouldn't do this even  you can.  Just  change to use  proper  conditional variable.